# Git merge branch from origin

Tags: git, merge

I have a bunch of remote (tracking) branches that I have created local branches from (so I can write, commit and push) eg. **origin/myfeature**. Now I would like to merge **origin/myfeature** into **master**.

I could do (assuming that I am currently on master):

```
git merge origin/myfeature
```

but is this guaranteed to pull latest changes (or be identical to what is in the central "truth") before performing merging?

As I understand locale remote tracking branches are not necessarily pointing to the latest remote changes on the branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do a `fetch`, that gets a snapshot of the origin. Then `merge` that snapshot. Certainly on origin it could gain some more stuff.

If you're concerned about that race, you can do another fetch before pushing your changes to see if it moved.   But still someone could add another commit before or during the time you push.

But before getting too excited about that, suppose you won the race. But someone added a patch *just after* your merge.   Is that different in any practical way?

In DVCS it's normal that additions happen, if they do, you do another merge to pick up the new stuff.   And races are not so interesting.

Comment: Is the fetch part of the merge command? If not I might as well merge from the local branch as I see it.

Comment: `fetch` would be part of the `pull` command.  So as long as your local is up-to-date you can merge with either one and it won't make a difference.

Comment: no, `fetch` is separate, `pull` is the combination. But it still has the same theoretical race condition just with shorter window to start with -- certainly by the time you resolved the conflicts and done all the checks it will be irrelevant

Comment: Ok so there is no difference between: "merge myfeature" and "merge origin/myfeature" ?

Comment: If they point at the same commit, there's no difference, except you get a slightly different default message.

Comment: If there is no difference between merge myfeature and merge origin/myfeature then what does the "origin" signify?  If it doesn't automatically merge from origin?